# Java: How to make 2 player alternate turns in Snake and Ladder Game?

Tags: java, arrays, controls, structure

This is a snake and ladder game where i cannot use array, i should only use control structures and method.

this is my code, i cannot make a second player turn end, i need to make each player alternate turn till one of them reach 100 . any solution please?

```
int score1,scorePlayer1,sum1=0;
int score2,scorePlayer2,sum2=0;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player1 you start");
do{
score1=rollDie();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score= "+score1);
}while(score1!=6);
if(score1==6){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "well done you now start at position1 on the board\nYour sum=1");
while(sum1<=100){
score1=rollDie();
sum1=sum1+score1;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score= "+score1+"\nYour new position= "+sum1);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player2 you start");
do{
score2=rollDie();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score= "+score2);
}while(score2!=6);
if(score2==6){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "well done you now start at position1 on the board\nYour sum=1");
while(sum1<=100){
score1=rollDie();
sum1=sum1+score1;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score= "+score1+"\nYour new position= "+sum1);
}
}
System.exit(0);
}
public static int rollDie(){
return (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Try using a variable that represents whose turn it is. See if you can come up with rules that tell you when to change that value, and rules to use it to decide what to display and what to do with the user input.

Comment: Please edit your question to indent your code. It is almost unreadable as it is. We hope that the people who ask questions will put as much effort into their questions as they expect from the volunteers who answer the questions.